# how to deal with unamanaged resoures in case of extension class?

Tags: c#, .net

There are two Classes ClassA and ClassB. ClassB extends ClassA. There are unmanaged resources in ClassA as well as ClassB.
So the question is : should Dispose() method be provided to both of these Classes or Dispose for ClassA will suffice

Edit1:
By the response I have got so far I think my statement has been misunderstood as ClassB inherits from ClassA. What I meant can be understood by visiting following links :

- [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx) page
- [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34209/Extension-Methods-in-C) page

Comment: By the response I have got so far I think my statement has been misunderstood as ClassB inherits from ClassA.
What I meant can be understood by visiting following links :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34209/Extension-Methods-in-C

Comment: Can you extend your question and highlight what you need? The articles are about something else totally (Extension methods)

Answer (score 3):

You will have to call the base `Dispose` from the child one. Implementing `Dispose` in Class B will overwrite the inherited method. This is because methods are virtual by default in C# (if re-implemented in child classes, the re-implementation will be called).

```
// Class B

public void Dispose()
{
    base.Dispose();

    // Dispose the rest (unmanaged B)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends whether `ClassB` introduces new disposable resources. If it does, `ClassA`'s `Dispose` method will not be able to dispose the new resources of `ClassB`. Use this pattern in `ClassA`

```
// In ClassA

public void Dispose()
{
    Dispose(true);

    // Only if you are using a finalizer
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}

protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing)
    {
        // get rid of managed resources
    }   
    // get rid of unmanaged resources
}
```

In `ClassB` you can override the virtual `Dispose(bool disposing)` method and do not have to re-implement the `IDisposable` interface.

```
// In ClassB

protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    base.Dispose(disposing);
    if (disposing)
    {
        // get rid of managed resources declared in ClassB
    }   
    // get rid of unmanaged resources declared in ClassB
}
```

A finalizer would call `Dispose(false);`.